# Getting Warning from require savon in ruby

Tags: ruby, savon

Ubuntu 18.04, ruby  2.5.1p57

I have a ruby program that I use on a number of different linux system.  On one it produces a screed of warning from `require 'savon'`

```
elasticsearch@secesprd02:~$ ruby /usr/local/tools/dev/es-cluster/bin/send-json.rb  -v --cluster test -c /usr/local/tools/dev/conf/conf.json  -r name=ES-api-winlogbeat json/winlogbeat-api-key
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/akami-1.3.1/lib/akami/wsse.rb:99: warning: shadowing outer local variable - key
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/akami-1.3.1/lib/akami/wsse.rb:99: warning: shadowing outer local variable - v1
/var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/akami-1.3.1/lib/akami/wsse.rb:99: warning: shadowing outer local variable - v2
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59: warning: loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/gyoku-1.3.1/lib/gyoku/hash.rb
    from /usr/local/tools/dev/es-cluster/bin/send-json.rb:8:in  `<main>'
    from /usr/local/tools/dev/es-cluster/bin/send-json.rb:8:in  `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/tools/dev/common-library/lib/app-configure.rb:3:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/tools/dev/common-library/lib/app-configure.rb:3:in  `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/tools/common-library/lib/SecretServer.rb:1:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in  `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in  `rescue in require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in  `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/savon-2.12.1/lib/savon.rb:26:in  `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in  `require'
...
```

The program runs without any obvious problems apart from the warings.

I have updated savon and akami gems but this made no difference.

Comment: You might want to upgrade your Ruby version(s) because it's not supported anymore. v2.5.x went EOL on 2021-04-05 (https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/branches/)

Answer (score 0):

The warning is caused due to

> loading in progress, circular require considered harmful - /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/gyoku-1.3.1/lib/gyoku/hash.rb

That should not cause you any harm, given that the `require` keeps track of files already loaded, so the behaviour of your application should not be affected in any way.

A good overview on that can be found on [this answer](https://rubytalk.org/t/circular-require-considered-harmful/74749/2).

> Under normal circumstances it's fine to require the same file twice, because require keeps a record of the libraries it has loaded and ignores a second call.
>
> It looks as if you get this error if the library you are requiring
> requires itself somehow, which is not something that require can cope
> with -- the require operation presumably needs to complete before the
> library is added to the list.
>
> So if in a.rb you require b.rb and in b.rb you require a.rb. then when you write `require "a"` Ruby will
>
> * start to require a.rb
>
> * start to require b.rb
>
> * start to require a.rb again and realise there is something terribly wrong.